# Why won't my model get passed?

Tags: backbone.js, requirejs

I have this collection view

```
 define([
     'jquery',
     'underscore',
     'backbone',
     'views/project',
     'collections/project-collection',
     'templates'
 ], function ($, _, Backbone, ProjectView, ProjectCollection, JST) {
'use strict';

var ProjectListView = Backbone.View.extend({
    template: JST['app/scripts/templates/projectList.ejs'],
    el: $('#content'),

    render: function() {
        var projectCollection = new ProjectCollection();
        projectCollection.fetch();
        projectCollection.each(this.addOne(),this);
        return this;
    },
    addOne: function(project) {
        console.log('addOne function');
        var projectView = new ProjectView({model: project});
        this.$el.html( projectView.render().el);
    }
});

     return ProjectListView;
});
```

No matter what I try the model never gets passed through to the addOne function so the in the view that is instantiated by this method the call to

```
  this.model.toJSON()
```

results in the old 'cannot call method .toJSON of undefined' error. I tried to inject the collection when this collection view was instantiated and that didn't work either. Obviously here it is in the dependency array and that doesn't work either. The model is definitely there as I can log projectCollection.model to the console inside the render function. I'm stumped.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I see two problems with your `render`: one you know about and one you don't.

The first problem is right here:

```
projectCollection.each(this.addOne(), this);
```

The parentheses on `this.addOne()` call the `addOne` method right there rather than passing the `this.addOne` function to `each` as a callback. You want this:

```
projectCollection.each(this.addOne, this);
```

The second problem is that you have to wait for the collection's `fetch` to return before anything will be in the collection. You can use the [`fetch`'s](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) callbacks:

```
var _this = this;
projectCollection.fetch({
    success: function() {
        projectCollection.each(_this.addOne, _this);
    }
});
```

or you can use the various events that `fetch` will fire, see the [`fetch`](http://backbonejs.org/#Collection-fetch) documentation for details.

Comment: I was thinking it was something like that. I tried to chain .then() to fetch and that didn't work. This totally works, thanks. I was suspicious of this not having the right context as well but really don't understand all that I know about context and closures yet.